# delete drill layer in eagle without redoing board

Tags: eaglecad, through-hole, drill

When I go to make my own circuit boards with eagle, after saving, I run the drill-aid.ulp script so eagle can convert all over-sized drill holes to small size. It helps me with drilling. I then saved my board again. I did this a few days ago.

Now this time, I load the same board and I want to undo that operation very quickly. I tried selecting the layers box and I scroll all the way down to:

```
116 CenterDrill
```

When I select Del, I get the message:

```
Layer '116 CenterDrill' is not empty.
```

Because I have at least a few hundred of these to remove, doing it manually will be a pain in the butt.

Is there some easy way for me to do this? even if it means me inventing some sort of script? I want the board to once again be at the state just before drill-aid.ulp was executed.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out. I had to hide all other layers, select the entire board (aka drill layers) then delete them then re-display the other layers.